# Python : Remodeling the presentation data from a pandas Dataframe / group duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, duplicates

Let's say that I have this dataframe with three column : "Name", "Account" and "Ccy".

```
import pandas as pd

Name = ['Dan', 'Mike', 'Dan', 'Dan', 'Sara', 'Charles', 'Mike', 'Karl']
Account = ['100', '30', '50', '200', '90', '20', '65', '230']
Ccy = ['EUR','EUR','USD','USD','','CHF', '','DKN']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':Name, 'Account' : Account, 'Ccy' : Ccy})


    Name    Account Ccy
0   Dan     100     EUR
1   Mike    30      EUR
2   Dan     50      USD
3   Dan     200     USD
4   Sara    90  
5   Charles 20      CHF
6   Mike    65  
7   Karl    230     DKN
```

I would like to reprensent this data differently. I would like to write a script that find all the duplicates in the column name and regroup them wit the different account and if there are an currency "Ccy", it add a new column next to it with all the currency associated.

So something like that :

```
    Dan Ccy1    Mike    Ccy2    Sara    Charles Ccy3    Karl    Ccy4
0   100 EUR     30      EUR     90      20      CHF     230     DKN
1   50  USD     65                      
2   200 USD
```

I dont' really know how to start that ! So I simplify the problem to do step y step. I try to regroup the dupicates by the name with a list however it did not identify the duplicates.

```
x_len, y_len = df.shape
new_data = []

for i in range(x_len) :
    
        if df.iloc[i,0] not in new_data :
            print(str(df.iloc[i,0]) + '\t'+ str(df.iloc[i,1])+ '\t' + str(bool(df.iloc[i,0] not in new_data)))
            new_data.append([df.iloc[i,0],df.iloc[i,1]])
            
        
        else: 
            new_data[str(df.iloc[i,0])].append(df.iloc[i,1])
```

Then I thought that it was easier to use a dictionary. So I try this loop but there is an error and maybe it is not the best way to go to the expected final result

```
from collections import defaultdict

dico=defaultdict(list)
x_len, y_len = df.shape

for i in range(x_len) :

    if df.iloc[i,0] not in dico :
        print(str(df.iloc[i,0]) + '\t'+ str(df.iloc[i,1])+ '\t' + str(bool(df.iloc[i,0] not in dico)))
        dico[str(df.iloc[i,0])] = df.iloc[i,1]
        print(dico)
    
    else : 
        dico[df.iloc[i,0]].append(df.iloc[i,1])
```

Anyone has an idea how to start or to do the code if it is simple ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last flatten columns names:

```
g = df.groupby(['Name']).cumcount()

df = df.set_index([g,'Name']).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df)
  Account_Charles Ccy_Charles Account_Dan Ccy_Dan Account_Karl Ccy_Karl  \
0              20         CHF         100     EUR          230      DKN   
1             NaN         NaN          50     USD          NaN      NaN   
2             NaN         NaN         200     USD          NaN      NaN   

  Account_Mike Ccy_Mike Account_Sara Ccy_Sara  
0           30      EUR           90           
1           65                   NaN      NaN  
2          NaN      NaN          NaN      NaN
```

If need custom columns names use `if-else` in list comprehension:

```
g = df.groupby(['Name']).cumcount()

df = df.set_index([g,'Name']).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
L = [b if a == 'Account' else f'{a}{i // 2}' for i, (a, b) in enumerate(df.columns)]
df.columns = L
print (df)
  Charles Ccy0  Dan Ccy1 Karl Ccy2 Mike Ccy3 Sara Ccy4
0      20  CHF  100  EUR  230  DKN   30  EUR   90     
1     NaN  NaN   50  USD  NaN  NaN   65       NaN  NaN
2     NaN  NaN  200  USD  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help ! It helped me a lot ! It is amaging, I have to study the functionalities of groupby() 

I have another question that is on the same structure of this one/ same content. I split it to go step y step to create my data before saving it in a csv file. Could you help me if you have time ? I will write it right now and post it
Thank you a lot and I wish you a lovely day

Comment: here is my new question, Thank you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555472/python-remodeling-the-presentation-of-the-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-group